# Chrome autofill credit card in input without name or autofill attributes

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome, autocomplete

Lately, we have added a custom React components library to our app (company standart). It has a limitation - doesn't allow to set `name` or `autocomplete` attribute. So, some of our inputs lost `name` attribute after an update.

After update our rendered input looks like this:

```html
<div class="search-input">
  <div class="sc-bYwzuL dnjiBM">
    <input data-test-id="navigation_customer-search-input" placeholder="Search for a customer" rows="1" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

And Chrome started to autofill it with credit cards info:

[image]

Maybe someone is aware of what can cause such behavior?

I was sure that credit cards autofill is only available when correct `name` or `autocomplete` attributes are provided (like described [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill)).

**Additional details:**

Before the library update input had no issue with autocomplete and was rendered like this:

```html
<div class="search-input-container">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for a customer" data-test-id="search__search-input__input" value="">
</div>
```

Also, when I'm deploying exactly the same version to a different environment with a different domain (which I wasn't using for a while) - I don't see an autofill issue.

Comment: Next Chromium issues seems to be related - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1158734&q=credit%20card&can=2

Comment: Explaination from Chromium team about how autocomplete is working: `The classification happened via crowdsourcing (in many cases, people entered a first name into the field, so Chrome classified it as a first name). I have created an override, which takes a few hours to propagate through the caches. Different domains are treated as independent forms. This is why a different dev environment would not be affected by my change.`

Comment: Apparently the resolution to this issue - use "name" attribute. I will check it in our app and get back with updates when tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1158734&q=credit%20card&can=2) Chrome uses crowdsourcing (when many people entered the first name into the field - Chrome will classify it as a first name) to identify how to autocomplete the field.

However, if your `input` has the correct [name](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_name.asp) and/or [autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) attribute - it will work accordingly to that attributes.

After applying this fix and testing I can say, that it was probably the only way to fix the issue.